# @-webkit-animation-name not allowing names/loops

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use `@-webkit-animation-name` and any name that I attach does not seem to register. It is grey in Atom, which if I am not mistaken, means: it is not a valid entry.

I'm not sure if it is related, but due to that I cannot use `@-webkit-keyframes fade{}` set an `opacity` value.

I am trying to set up an automatically scrolling banner/gallery as shown here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

The current troublesome snippet for me is:

```
.fade{
-webkit-animation-name: fade;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}
```

`animation-name` and `-webkit-animation-name` for "fade" are both greyed out.

For `@-webkit-keyframes fade`, at opacity is grey as well, which is odd since `@keyframes fade {from: ... }` is not seen as invalid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without providing your full codes (complete HTML and CSS, so a fiddle could be run on jsfiddle.net), you chance for gaining a reliable answer is too low.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up ata.

https://jsfiddle.net/57f1z84c/

This is what I currently worked on. Its the first time that I'm trying out coding. Instead of starting a new question, if anyone can answer my earlier question and can point out as to why my animation is not loading correctly, I would appreciate it. 

I am trying to use the https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/18/3d-thumbnail-hover-effects/comment-page-2/#comments to make some image/thumbnails responsive to hover over.

Thank you.

Sorry for the double post. Didnt know the 5 min rule.